# Yet another duplicated answers linked to own blog, and questions should be close as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670885/paul-mason) answered 7 exact same answers just link to his blog.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A670885+isaccepted%3A0

One of [his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/how-to-code-a-url-shortener/5747592#5747592) (edit: now deleted) started getting spam flags. And I think he would get more flags eventually.

His answer on his blog looks very good one, but as ever, its useless without looking at his blog.

And, almost all the questions he answered are look like exact duplicates except this one - [How to code a URL shortener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742013/) (edit: now deleted too).

Comment: You're completely right, but I fail to see how further discussion is useful. You've already flagged, right?

Comment: This is *clearly* spam. I've flagged it anyway. If it was on a fresh question with a bit more content than only a link and he didn't do it consitently, it wouldn't have been seen as spam.

Comment: At least he's a self-professed expert in SEO

Comment: Oh, the last question which you linked is not from the very same user. It was one of the questions where he spammed his blog (by the way, why was your comment deleted?).

Comment: @Chichiray, yeah, questions are not from him, but he answered those. I just wanted to mentioned that he could same answer on multiple questions because questions are looks like duplicates. (And I deleted my comment, because I changed my mind to flag those also but already gone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started flagging his answers, not only because all of them pointed to his own blog, but also because all of them contained the same body text, and he got my attention because some of his answers were listed under the "new answers to old questions".

Now, providing an old question a new answer consisting of a pointer to your own blog, is clear spam in my book.